# PF Firewall on OSX with IceFloor

Tags: firewall, mac-osx, pf

I have set up pf using IceFloor on my OSX 10.9 system running Server 3.0.2. Everything seems to be fine except that I can not connect to the system using the DNS name or the public IP from localhost. E.g. I can connect to http/port 80 from the internet, but not from the machine itself using the public IP. The connection from the machine to localhost/127.0.0.1 works. Here is the log I get (x.x.x.x is the public IP of the host):

```
rule 7/0(match): block in on en0: x.x.x.x.80 > x.x.x.x.64460: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 1, win 65535, length 0
```

And here is the list of rules

```
$ sudo pfctl -s rules
[sudo] password for paul: 
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
scrub-anchor "icefloor.nat" all fragment reassemble
anchor "icefloor.nat" all
block drop in quick from <emergingthreats> to any
block drop out quick from any to <emergingthreats>
block drop in log quick from <_blacklist> to any
block drop out log quick from any to <_blacklist>
block drop in quick from no-route to any
block drop in quick from urpf-failed to any label "uRPF"
block drop log inet all label "Generic_blocks_(IPv4)"
block drop log inet6 all label "Generic_blocks_(IPv6)"
anchor "icefloor.groupblocks" all label "Blocks"
anchor "inspector.blocks" all label "Temp_blocks"
anchor "icefloor.exceptions" all label "Logs_exceptions"
anchor "icefloor.portknocking" all label "Hidden_services"
anchor "icefloor.genericipv6" all
anchor "icefloor.inbound" all label "Local_services"
anchor "icefloor.outbound" all label "All_traffic"
anchor "icefloor.outbound_nat" all label "NAT_clients_traffic"
anchor "icefloor.custom_rules" all
```

Can you tell me which one the `rule 7/0(match)` is? And why it is not allowed to connect from localhost to the public key (on any open ports)? Has it something to do with the `no-route` f rule? Or the two `Generic_blocks_`-rules?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too was facing this issue and it took quiet a bit of testing and `tcpdump` to figure it all out.

To answer your first question, which one the `rule 7/0(match)` is: It is the "Generic_blocks_(IPv4)" rule automatically added by IceFloor to block and log all non-explicitly authorized traffic. You can confirm that rule's number by running `pfctl -gsr` as root.

On to the reason why it is blocked. The inbound connection is what is blocked. It has nothing to do with the no-route or anything in the *visible* ruleset. It has to do with how your DNS name is handled locally. Your machine's routing table (`netstat -r`) has an entry for your DNS name that points to `localhost` on the `lo0` interface.

The log entry contains some puzzling information, specifically the `block in on en0`, which leads you to believe something is happening on interface `en0`. However, doing a `tcpdump -nvvvi en0 tcp and port 80` showed that no packets were actually traveling on `en0`. Packets were, however, found with `tcpdump -nvvvi lo0 tcp and port 80`, thus confirming that the traffic was (as expected) happening on `lo0`.

The default IceFloor configuration (`/Library/IceFloor/icefloor.conf`) is generated with a line that has `set skip on lo0`. At first, this seems like a very standard, welcomed line (see http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/options.html). Every other piece of `lo0` appeared unhindered by the pf rules. On a hunch, I decided to comment out that line and add a new rule (just after the table include): `pass quick on lo0`. After reloading with this modified configuration, I was successfully able to access my web server via my DNS name (problem solved). So it looks like the `set skip on lo0` line has some issues.

The setback with manually modifying the `icefloor.conf` file is that it then prevents you from using the Firewall tab in the IceFloor interface. As saving a new configuration would override any manual edits.

Comment: The file "/Applications/IceFloor.app/Contents/Resources/pflists.conf" appears to be used by IceFloor to generate "/Library/IceFloor/icefloor.conf". After editing "pflists.conf", clicking "Apply" on IceFloor's "Firewall" tab builds "/Library/IceFloor/icefloor.conf" with the modifications from "pflists.conf". O.K. as a workaround but still wondering why "set skip on lo0" doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: If you try to modify the `plists.conf` as @TomCarpenter describes, note that you can't simply comment out `set skip on lo0` and replace it with `pass quick on lo0` b/c **IceFloor** insists that the rules be grouped in a certain order… And also there are three or so other `*.conf` files that may be used depending on what options are selected in the GUI.